# Text going off page while using pdfmake library

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake to get users to fill out a form and the data from that form is taken and converted into a PDF. But the issue is when a user types in a long text the text goes off page.

I have tried settings style to justify but that does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
 <title>my first pdfmake example</title>
 <script src='pdfmake.min.js'></script>
 <script src='vfs_fonts.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="test" name="test">
<textarea id="z" cols="10" rows="5" wrap="hard"></textarea>

<button onclick="pdf()">generate</button>
<script>

    // open the PDF in a new window
    function pdf() {
        var x = document.getElementById("test").value
        var z = document.getElementById("z").value

        var docDefinition = {

            content: [

                {
                    image: 'sampleImage.png',
                },

                {  ul: [x] },
                {
                    image: 'sampleImage.png'
                },

                {

                    ul: [
                           'Item 1',
                           'Item 2',
                           'Item 3',
                        {
                            text: z,
                            bold: true,
                            alignment: 'justify'
                        },
                   ],

                }
                ],

            styles: {
                header: {
                    fontSize: 18,
                    bold: true,
                    alignment: 'justify'
                }
            }
        };
        //alert(x);
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

**THE ERROR:**

In the image you can see putting in a long text goes off screen.

[image]

**Is there anyway of fixing that no matter how long the text user enters doesnt go off screen. it goes to the next line?**

Comment: Add `width` in `ul` by script which you use. where is you give the property `text: z,
                            bold: true,
                            alignment: 'justify',

Answer (score 1):

As @jthoenes said on 18 Feb at https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/204, pdfmake *never breaks words*, it only breaks when you have a whitespace or punctation.

Below this lines I have attached a simple code that you can paste directly at [pdfmake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) in order to try it. You will see that only withespace or punctuation achieves your needs.

Good luck!

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines',
        {
            ul: [
                'Item 1',
                'Item 2',
                'Item 3',
                {
                    text: 'thisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatest.thisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatest',
                    bold: true,
                    alignment: 'justify',
                    margin: [10,10,10,10],
                    width:90
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            text: 'thisisatest.thisisatestthisisatest.thisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatest',

            alignment: 'justify',
            margin: [0,190,10,80],
            width:90
        },
        {
            columns: [
                {
                    width:90,
                    text: 'thisisatest.thisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatestthisisatest!'

                }, 
                {
                    width: '*',
                    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Malit profecta versatur nomine ocurreret multavit, officiis viveremus aeternum superstitio suspicor alia nostram, quando nostros congressus susceperant concederetur leguntur iam, vigiliae democritea tantopere causae, atilii plerumque ipsas potitur pertineant multis rem quaeri pro, legendum didicisse credere ex maluisset per videtis. Cur discordans praetereat aliae ruinae dirigentur orestem eodem, praetermittenda divinum. Collegisti, deteriora malint loquuntur officii cotidie finitas referri doleamus ambigua acute. Adhaesiones ratione beate arbitraretur detractis perdiscere, constituant hostis polyaeno. Diu concederetur.'
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```